# ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama'

Tags: colorama

I'm trying to execute bayesian optimizer but I always get the same error.
I tried "pip install -U colorama" but it still doesn't work

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13036\1140567575.py in <module>
----> 1 from colorama import just_fix_windows_console
      2 just_fix_windows_console()

ImportError: cannot import name 'just_fix_windows_console' from 'colorama'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Import BayesianOptimization from bayes\_opt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745944/cant-import-bayesianoptimization-from-bayes-opt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. For me, the following worked:

```
pip install colorama=0.4.4
pip install bayesian-optimization=1.4.0
```